# How can I use GROUP_CONCAT with multiple values?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I want to get some data via php from my SQL database:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.name SEPARATOR ",") AS cats
```

this gives me a list:

```
sam, john, joe
```

I get some other data like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.id SEPARATOR ",") AS cat_ids
```

here I get the result

```
1,2,3
```

Now here is my problem. I want to combine these values to get a result like this:

```
<a href="1">sam</a><a href="2">john</a><a href="3">joe</a>
```

My approach:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("<a href=\'",cat.id,"\'>",cat.name,"</a>")) AS cats
```

But here I only get a blank white page as a result.

Comment: I found out is working, the blank white page was caused by another reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just used single quotes for string and double quote for attribute html.  Moreover I used a space (" ") as separator in GROUP_CONCAT

```
CREATE TABLE GC1 (name VARCHAR(20), id INT);

    INSERT INTO GC1 VALUES ('sam',1);
    INSERT INTO GC1 VALUES ('john',2);
    INSERT INTO GC1 VALUES ('joe',3);
    SELECT * FROM GC1;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('<a href="',id,'">',name,'</a>') SEPARATOR " ") AS X FROM GC1;
```

Output:

```
<a href="1">sam</a> <a href="2">john</a> <a href="3">joe</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href = "', `cat`.`id`, '">', `cat`.`name`, '</a>') SEPARATOR '') AS `cats`
```

worked for me